# How can I add an active selector to this piece of code

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Can anyone help me with adding an active selector so that when a link is clicked that link will receive a different color background or maybe just bold it?

Filename is section.html

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="container-inner">
    {{breadcrumbs}}
    <div class="search-box search-box_page">
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 25 26">
    <path d="M20,18.9c1.6-2.1,2.4-4.6,2.4-7.2c0-6.4-5-11.7-11.2-11.7C5,0,0,5.3,0,11.7s5,11.7,11.2,11.7
          c2.5,0,5-0.9,6.9-2.5l4.6,4.8c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.4,0.9,0.4c0.3,0,0.7-0.1,0.9-0.4c0.5-0.6,0.5-1.4,0-2L20,18.9z M20,12
          c0,4.9-3.8,9-8.5,9s-9.1-4.1-9.1-9s4.4-9.5,9.1-9.5S20,7,20,12z"/>
  </svg>
  {{search instant=true placeholder=settings.search_placeholder}}
</div>

        <div class="section group">
    <div class="left-nav col span_1_of_2_">
    <h2 class="leftnav-title">Support</h2>
        <ul style="color:#333;">
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test1.com"><li>Manuals</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test2.com"><li>International</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test3.com"><li>Tracking</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test4.com"><li>Contacts</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test5.com"><li>Security</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test6.com"><li>Registration</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test7.com"><li>Policy</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test8.com"><li>Troubleshooting</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test9.com"><li>Promotions</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test10.com"><li>Shipping</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test11.com"><li>Terms</li></a>
      <a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test12.com"><li>Claim</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col span_1_of_2">
        <div style="" class="category-tree" id="section">
      <section class="category-tree__item">
        <h2 class="category-tree__title">{{section.name}}</h2>
      <div class="accordion-wrapper">
  {{#each section.articles}}
  <ul data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{id}}" class="article-list article-list_page">
    <li class="article-list__item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="cursor: default;" class="art-title">{{title}}</a>
      <article style="font-weight:100;" id="{{id}}" class="article-body collapse art-body">
      {{body}}
      </article>
    </li>
  </ul>
  {{/each}}
</div>
    </div>
</div>


      </section>
      {{pagination}}
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code:

```
<script>
require(['jquery'], function($){ 
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.section ul li').click(function(e){
              $('.section ul li').removeClass('active');
              $(this).addClass('active');
               e.preventDefault();
         });
    });
});
</script>
```

Add the below css as well for bold the active anchor.

```
<style>
.section .active{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

If you are using ul then use li like below as well:

```
<div class="section group"> <div class="left-nav col span_1_of_2_"> <ul style="color:#333;">
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Registration</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Status</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Instruction</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Links</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Policy</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Troubleshooting</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">International</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Shipping</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Promotions</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Payment</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Contacts</a></li>
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Terms</a> </li>
</ul> </div>
```

Comment: Hi, why we need jquery ui in the code?

Comment: No need to use jQuery ui. Miss place.

Comment: @SukumarGorai The page refreshes when I click any link so wouldn't I need some type of javascript? The bold will not be there after the page refreshes.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: @SukumarGorai That's not working for me

Comment: What is the issue are getting?

Comment: Nothing is being bold

Comment: Check the updated answer also update the html as well

Comment: @SukumarGorai I did but nothing

Comment: Did you update the css as well? Can you check the console if any errors?

Comment: I am testing it on a jsfiddle and no errors @SukumarGorai

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2wt43L1j/3/#&togetherjs=uLfuxhSPvi

Comment: Wait I am sending you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2wt43L1j/12/ Please check this its working fine. Something is wrong with your end.

Comment: @SukumarGorai When I put that into my code my links are not going anywhere just staying in the same place

Comment: I know if you want to use the same when page refresh then you need to use cookie or session otherwise how do you capture which link was clicked.

Comment: @SukumarGorai How can I do that?

Comment: Please paste your whole code along with the file name on your question.

Comment: @SukumarGorai ok all code was pasted

Comment: @SukumarGorai Any idea?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79865/discussion-on-answer-by-sukumar-gorai-how-can-i-add-an-active-selector-to-this-p).

Answer (score -1):

I would comment to inquire further, but I'm a bit new here.

I would move the a href to inside the li item.

ul > li > a

```
<li><a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com">Registration</a></li>
```

instead of (what you have now)

ul > a > li

```
<a class="link-leftbar" href="www.test.com"><li>Registration</li></a>
```

Are you looking to have an :active selector? Or are you trying to make sure that it reflects that someone visited prior?

```
a.link-leftbar:active{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

The CSS may need more specific if the ul is overriding it.

```
ul li a.link-leftbar:active{
font-weight: bold;
}
```

I haven't tested, so your milage may vary. Be sure to clear your browser cache and try in the default store view > Scripts and Style Sheets to place it in the head to see if the CSS works.

I would try to avoid jQuery if it's not needed.